# Getting Postcode From Google Map Search

Tags: google-maps

I have code that will find postcode from long/lat, which I could use with the code below, but (I think) this will be seen as several requests (dont want to burn my google quota).

Is there any other way that I can get the below could to show postcode as part of the auto complete, ideally in another field..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />




  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>


 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=HERE&amp;libraries=places"></script>

<script>
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    function initialize() {
      var input = document.getElementById('autocomplete_search');
      var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
      autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function () {
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

      // place variable will have all the information you are looking for.
      $('#lat').val(place.geometry['location'].lat());
      $('#long').val(place.geometry['location'].lng());
    });
  }
</script>


  <title>Google Places Autocomplete InputBox Example Without Showing Map - Tutsmake.com</title>
 <style>
    .container{
    padding: 10%;
    text-align: center;
   } 
 </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12"><h2>Google Places Autocomplete InputBox Example Without Showing Map</h2></div>
        <div class="col-12">
            <div id="custom-search-input">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input id="autocomplete_search" name="autocomplete_search" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="lat">
                    <input type="hidden" name="long">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the address components of the PlaceResult and parse them for the postal code as is done in the [Place Autocomplete Address Form Example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform)

```
autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function () {
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }

  // Get each component of the address from the place details,
  // and then fill-in the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }

  // place variable will have all the information you are looking for.
  $('#lat').val(place.geometry.location.lat());
  $('#long').val(place.geometry.location.lng());
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/s6cjeaq0/)

[image: screenshot of result]

Comment: Thanks for this. I came across it while searching for the answer, but cant seem to get the zip/postal code to populate when I place an address in the top field.

Comment: Do you see the issue with the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/s6cjeaq0/) in my answer?  If so, what address are you having the issue with (not all places have postcodes).  If not, then it is likely an issue with your key (and a different/new question).  What error messages are you getting?

Comment: Seems ok with US addresses but when using known UK addresses it not displaying the postcode.