# Google Places API autocomplete zipcode in different input field

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I have 2 input fields on my website, one for the customers full address and the other is for the zip code. I need to have it as 2 different input fields, for database reasons.
I want to have autocomplete on my website. I have been able to get Google Places API to work. But I want it to autocomplete the address in one input field and automatically the zip code in another field.

How to do it?

This is my code current code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var autocompleteFrom;
    autocompleteFrom = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((document.getElementById('fromInput')), {
        types: ['address'],
        componentRestrictions: {
            country: 'dk'
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

related questions:

- [How to get the country code from Google Places API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33887081/how-to-get-the-country-code-from-google-places-api)
- [Getting Postcode From Google Map Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57445278/getting-postcode-from-google-map-search)

There is a related example in the Google Maps Javascript API v3 documentation that can be modified to just get the postal code from the AutoComplete response: [Place Autocomplete Address Form](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform)

Change the `component_form` object to just include the `postal_code`:

```
var componentForm = {
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};
```

Then call the `fillInAddress` function when the `place_changed` event fires:

```
autocompleteFrom.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/s0czwLyn/1/)

[image: screenshot of result]

**code snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var autocompleteFrom;
  var placeSearch;

  var componentForm = {
    postal_code: 'short_name'
  };
  autocompleteFrom = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((document.getElementById('fromInput')), {
    types: ['address'],
    componentRestrictions: {
      country: 'dk'
    }
  });
  // When the user selects an address from the drop-down, populate the
  // address fields in the form.
  autocompleteFrom.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);

  function fillInAddress() {
    // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
    var place = autocompleteFrom.getPlace();
    console.log(place);
    for (var component in componentForm) {
      document.getElementById(component).value = '';
      document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
    }

    // Get each component of the address from the place details,
    // and then fill-in the corresponding field on the form.
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
      var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
      if (componentForm[addressType]) {
        var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
        document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>address</label><input id="fromInput" /><br />
<label>postal code</label><input id="postal_code" />
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places"></script>
```

Comment: What should I do if I have multiple input fields on the same page?
I have From address input field and a from zip code input field, and I have an to address and to zip code input field... I can't name both toZipcode og fromZipcode with the id="postal_code"... How can I change that?

Comment: Does this help? [Google Maps API autocomplete 2nd address fields on same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33547312/google-maps-api-autocomplete-2nd-address-fields-on-same-page)